# check if url is a root url

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking for a regex to test if a url is a root url:

```
http://site.org                     TRUE
http://www.example.com              TRUE
...
http://www.example.com/dir          FALSE
http://www.example.com/image.jpg    FALSE
http://www.example.com/dir/file.doc FALSE
```

Comment: Will there always be a "http://"?

Comment: Are you testing the *current* URL, or one in an `<a href>`, or just one in a string?

Comment: Gralien: yes; Gareth: testing a string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below `regex` will do the work

```
/^https?\:\/\/[^\/]+\/?$/
```

I tested like this:

```
var URL = "http://jsfiddle.net/";
var check =/^https?\:\/\/[^\/]+\/?$/.test(URL);
alert(check);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wSETq/)

Comment: but, adding query string won't work

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var str='url...';
if(str.indexOf("/")<str.indexOf(".")&&(str.indexOf("http://")>-1))
  return true;
else
  return fals;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out with this regular expression

(?\w+)://(?[\w@][\w.:@]+)/?[\w.?=%&=-@/$,]*